# is there a way to generalize the number of sets satisfying these conditions into a formula?

Tags: combinatorics

$B_i$ is a subset of  $\mathbb{N}$ such that

- $$\sum_{x \in B_i}x = i$$
- $$ \text{card}(B_i) \leq i$$
- $$\forall x \in B_i \:\:  x\leq i  $$

$i$ is a non-zero integer

my goal is to find a general formula for the number of possible subsets that satisfy those 3 conditions.

example : 
if $i = 3 $  then the number of solutions is $3$ because $1+1+1 = 1+2 = 3$

if $i = 4 $  then the number of solutions is $5$ because $1+1+1+1 = 1+1+2=1+3=2+2 = 4$

I tried coding an algorithm to test all the possible cases and thereupon noticing a pattern or something but if $i$ is greater than $5$ it just takes too much time... it never ends.

any help would be greately appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Note that, technically, $\{1,1,1,1\}$ is the same subset as $\{1\}$.  These $B_i$, allowing repeats, are called partitions. The entire movie "The Man Who Knew Infinity" hinges on the difficulty of computing the partition function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Ferrers_diagram